# JMeter response 504 Gateway time-out?

Tags: jmeter, xmlhttprequest, timeout, gateway

I am trying to perform a test against an endpoint with 1 thread. I configured a HTTP request with JSON Monk endpoint [URL](https://jsonmonk.com/api/v1/users?page=1) using JMEter.
But when I run the test I get **Response code:504** in the Sampler result. The same when I use the URL in a browser I get also **504 Gateway Time-out**
Can anyone help me with this issue? - I tried in another pc and I got the same error!
I have installed JMeter correctly and my code is correct too. I am working on a Windows 10.
[image: log]
[image: Sampler_result]
[image: Response_data]
HTTP Request:
[image: Http_request]

Comment: @ user7294900: I added the HTTP Request, any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [HTTP Status Code 504 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 504 Gateway Timeout server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not get a response in time from the upstream server that it needed in order to complete the request.

> Note: **A Gateway might refer to different things in networking and a 504 error is usually not something you can fix, but requires a fix by the web server or the proxies you are trying to get access through.**

So it indicates the problem with the server you're trying to test, if you own the website - go and fix it, if you know someone who is responsible for it - inform him/her/them.

There is nothing you can do from JMeter perspective. If you know how response should look like you can use a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) to return this response so you could play with the response data

By the way, it's down for me as well:

[image]

Comment: @Dimitri_T: thanks. I figured it out after I posted my question. I was in doubt!, but thanks again.